# Show / hide div - removing clicked link

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have this script http://jsfiddle.net/s2CtY/ but what l need it an amendment so that the click link is hidden.  Basically the contents of the hidden div replaces the clicked link.

In addition there will be multiple instances of this on a page via PHP - how do l stop one click opening all ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub-nav ul').css("display", "none");

    // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
    $('.sub-nav-btn').click(function () {
        $(this).next(".sub-nav ul").slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- script above added by stack snippet -->

<div class="sub-nav">
    <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn1</div>
    <ul>btn1 slide data</ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
    <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn2</div>
    <ul>btn2 data slide</ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
    <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn3</div>
    <ul>btn3 data</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by one click opening all?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2CtY/14/), just to make sure that this is what you want, ill continue with your second request

add *(underneath your .click() function)*

```
$('.sub-nav').on('click', 'ul', function () {
      $(this).prev(".sub-nav-btn").slideToggle(400);
      $(this).slideToggle(400);
      return false;
});
```

**edit:** If understood correctly your second question is also solved. [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2CtY/16/)
2 instances of the div, on clicking shows only immediate prev() and next()

(well this is a cool feature :D)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub-nav ul').css("display","none");
    // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
    $('.sub-nav-btn').click(function () {
        $(this).next(".sub-nav ul").slideToggle(400);
        $(this).slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
    $('.sub-nav').on('click', 'ul', function () {
        $(this).prev(".sub-nav-btn").slideToggle(400);
        $(this).slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn1</div>
  <ul>btn1 slide data
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn2</div>
  <ul>btn2 data slide
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn3</div>
  <ul>btn3 data
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn1</div>
  <ul>btn1 slide data
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn2</div>
  <ul>btn2 data slide
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn3</div>
  <ul>btn3 data
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect - is there a way of adding an external link ? i.e.<div class="sub-nav">
    <div class="sub-nav-btn"><a href="www.yahoo.com">btn1</a></div>
    <ul>btn1 slide data</ul>
</div>

Comment: @Grant you mean instead of a normal div?

Comment: @Grant you could either do it with an anchor tag or add `onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/')"` event from the html to open a new tab

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want exactly, but you can hide the link when it's clicked and show it again on a click on the details, like this:

**JavaScript**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.sub-nav ul').css("display", "none");
       $(document).on("click", ".sub-nav-btn", function () {
           $(this).next(".sub-nav ul").slideDown(400);
           $(this).hide();
           return false;
       });

       $(document).on("click", ".sub-nav ul", function () {
           $(this).slideUp(400, function () {
               $(this).siblings(".sub-nav-btn").show();
           });
       });
   });
```

If I misunderstood you, please elaborate.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s2CtY/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is also an option. You basically get the children from the *.sub-nav* and toggle them.
This assumes that you only have these two elements. Try the snippet below (click on run code)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub-nav ul').css("display", "none");

    // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
    $('.sub-nav-btn, .sub-nav ul').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().children().slideToggle(400);
      
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- script above added by stack snippet -->

<div class="sub-nav">
    <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn1</div>
    <ul>btn1 slide data</ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
    <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn2</div>
    <ul>btn2 data slide</ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
    <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn3</div>
    <ul>btn3 data</ul>
</div>
```